# Idea for beginner's OpenMP project

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a parallel programming project that I have to do in C++ and openMP that's due in a week, and I was wondering if someone could give me an idea on something a beginner in both C++ and OpenMP can accomplish in this time. I've got pretty extensive experience in Java, but this class randomly started us on C++ without it being introduced to us before had (and I understand 80% of learning code should be on my own time, but I expected more forewarning before they throw a new language at us). The instructor hasn't given us any ideas, our labs have just been tutorials through basics, and our lectures have been about how to implement bits and pieces of parallel programming... so I'm at a loss at what would be good enough for a class project. It's an elective class, so he's not expecting much, but I just don't know where to start. Thanks guys

Comment: EDIT: is making a maze generator algorithm easy enough to learn at a very beginner level? I think it sounds interesting, but I don't want to waste time if it's not something I can learn to do in the week alloted

Comment: Quicksort might be useful

Comment: Quicksort is interesting, but you need tasks to implement it properly, which is advanced OpenMP feature. I don't think it is suitable for beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basics examples for OpenMP are computing PI and matrix multiplication.

More interesting topics may be:

1. [Image convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) (edge detection, sharpening, blurring, etc.). You could use [NetPBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) image format for simplicity.
2. [K-Means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

You could find serial C++ examples in the Internet and adopt them to OpenMP, which is relatively easy task.